# Disconnected Excel Front End Tool for a Complex database

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

I need suggestion on a excel data collection form for a complex relational database (Access/SQL). The excel need to be be designed in such a way it can be distributed as any other collection form (like simple paper or word document) and collected data should be imported easily to the main database.

I have created an excel that stores data and relationships in the multiple tables. Please consider the following example tables

```
Table1-in Excel
Client_ID Client_Name
1         John
2         Rebeka

Table2-in Excel 
Insurance_ID Insurance
1         Metlife Gold
2         Max full term
3         IFFCO full term 

Table3-in Excel
Client_ID Insurance_ID
1         1
2         1
1         2
1         3
```

---

Tables in MS Access

```
Table1
Client_ID Client_Name
1001     xyz
---     --
---     --
9001     abc

Table2
Insurance_ID Insurance 
10001     xyz
---     --
---     --
90001     zyff

Table3
Client_ID Insurance_ID
10001     1000
---     --
---     --
90001     1395
```

I am looking for an easy solution to append Table1 & Table3 rows from excel to corresponding Tables in Ms Access by generating new IDs in Table1 & table2 and updating the same in Table3. There are 20+ such tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should not be using Excel as a front end to Access. You can enter what ever you want in Excel with no data checking, like a string value in an integer field.

Comment: Thanks Chunk. It was client requirement. A possible solution is to generate a unique key based current date & time , this way I just need to append data directly without taking care of ids

Comment: Sure that could work, we just use to have lots of problems with Excel as a front end, but we stopped doing that about 15 years ago. Good luck!